# Dual booting (Ubuntu 14.04) and Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I just tried (and successfully I guess) installed Ubuntu (14.04 at least) to my computer (I don't know which of my 2 HDD or my SSD it installed to). I chose the `install along side Windows 7` option, I can get into Ubuntu - and I'm typing this from Ubuntu . . .  I can get into Windows 7 but `Windows Explorer` doesn't work, seems like I need to reformat again.  How can I get BOTH operating systems to be fully usable with Ubuntu getting about 250 - 300 GB of my 2TB internal hard drive?

Comment: Best to see details. Post link to summary report above. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9839882/  is the output.

Comment: You have Windows boot loaders in sdb & sdc, but Windows is in sda. And you have grub in the MBR of sda, but Ubuntu in sdb. I would use Boot-Repair's advanced mode and install a Windows boot loader to sda, and install grub to sdb. Then in BIOS boot from drive that is sdb. You also have a very large / (root) partition. Generally better to have a smaller / partition of 25GB and use rest of drive as /home or /mnt/data and often other partitions like a shared NTFS data partition. Your / is using 4.6GB of 1.7TB.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have the following partitions:

- 120GB SSD containing Windows installation
- 2TB HDD containing the Windows BOOT partition, a SWAP partition, and a nearly 2TB Ubuntu partition
- 3TB NTFS partition for data I assume.

What you want to do as far as I understand:

- resize the nearly 2TB Ubuntu partition to 300GB
- reformat the leftover place to NTFS

For this you can use a Live CD, install `gparted`, and set up the partitions as you see fit.

PS: And I don't know what you mean by both operating systems being usable, please elaborate in a comment.

Comment: I believe it's all solved, yes Windows 7 is on a SSD, Ubuntu on a ~300GB partition of my 2TB HDD with the rest of the space (of the same drive) for Windows files). And a 3TB for my Windows steam games.

Comment: If this has helped you, please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer.